# SQL how to update a row from a row above?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with products configuration.

[image]

Id_conf are connected with products (colspan_title) by row with a title and numbers of rows in colspan_no i.e. id_conf 4461-4465 are connected with colspan_title from a row 4461.

How to write a query which join every id_conf with colspan_title?
Is it possible to update a cell from a cell above?

Data in text:

```
id_conf position    proj_id colspan_no  colspan_title  
4460    1           575     1           prod1  
4461    2           575     5           prod2  
4462    3           575     0     
4463    4           575     0     
4464    5           575     0     
4465    6           575     0     
4466    7           575     2           prod3  
4467    8           575     0     
4468    9           575     3           prod4  
4469    11          575     0     
4470    10          575     0     
4471    12          575     3           prod5  
4472    14          575     0     
4473    13          575     0
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT
all id_conf have colspan_title

Thanks
DS

Comment: Post the sample data as text, not images and also post your expected output to clarify what you want.

Comment: Also tag the RDBMS that you are using along with its version.

Comment: ok how to paste sample data? just copy paste? sorry I'm new here id_conf position proj_id colspan_no colspan_title
4460 1 575 1 prod1
4461 2 575 5 prod2
4462 3 575 0 
4463 4 575 0 
4464 5 575 0 
4465 6 575 0 
4466 7 575 2 prod3
4467 8 575 0 
4468 9 575 3 prod4
4469 11 575 0 
4470 10 575 0 
4471 12 575 3 prod5
4472 14 575 0 
4473 13 575 0

Comment: If you [edit] your question, the editor toolbar has a question mark icon that gives you help about formatting your text. If you click that, there is a help topic about formatting tables. The whole list of formatting option is shown when you click the [Advanced help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions `SUM()` and `FIRST_VALUE()` in an updatable CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, FIRST_VALUE(colspan_title) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY id_conf) title
  FROM (
    SELECT *, SUM(colspan_no) OVER (ORDER BY id_conf) grp
    FROM tablename
  ) t  
)
UPDATE cte 
SET colspan_title = title
WHERE colspan_no = 0
```

If the order of the rows is not defined by `id_conf` but by `position` change `ORDER BY id_conf` in the `OVER` clauses of both `SUM()` and `FIRST_VALUE()` with `ORDER BY position`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6d3dd2155e8c8ee8c05d65b3c986ff77).
Results:

```
> id_conf | position | proj_id | colspan_no | colspan_title
> ------: | -------: | ------: | ---------: | :------------
>    4460 |        1 |     575 |          1 | prod1        
>    4461 |        2 |     575 |          5 | prod2        
>    4462 |        3 |     575 |          0 | prod2        
>    4463 |        4 |     575 |          0 | prod2        
>    4464 |        5 |     575 |          0 | prod2        
>    4465 |        6 |     575 |          0 | prod2        
>    4466 |        7 |     575 |          2 | prod3        
>    4467 |        8 |     575 |          0 | prod3        
>    4468 |        9 |     575 |          3 | prod4        
>    4469 |       11 |     575 |          0 | prod4        
>    4470 |       10 |     575 |          0 | prod4        
>    4471 |       12 |     575 |          3 | prod5        
>    4472 |       14 |     575 |          0 | prod5        
>    4473 |       13 |     575 |          0 | prod5        
>    4474 |       15 |     575 |          3 | prod6        
>    4475 |       17 |     575 |          0 | prod6        
>    4476 |       16 |     575 |          0 | prod6
```

Comment: It seems to be what I want but I can check it in a few hours to be sure. I can understand shit form your code now but yesterday I bought Ben Gan's book about window function so my intuition is better then skills ;) Thanks for now and I will reply later after checking.

Comment: It works perfect. Thank you. Strange thing is it should work rather with position than id_conf but when I change these two order by, output is wrong. But with id_conf works perfectly.

Comment: @DSQuest check for irregularities in the column `position`. From the sample data you posted I see that it is not always in ascending order.

Comment: Ok now I know how  it works - positions are the same in every proj_id and this is why output was wrong. When I order by proj_id, postion everything is ok. Definitely my New Year resolution is to learn window functions ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have `position` column also, which can be used as follows to update the `colspan_title` of all rows where `colspan_no` is 0:

```
update your_table t
set t.colspan_title = (select tt.colspan_title from your_table tt
                        where tt.colspan_no > 0 and t.proj_id = tt.proj_id
                          and t.position between tt.colspan_no 
                                             and tt.colspan_no + tt.position - 1)
where t.colspan_no = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Problem is that in select there is a list of all colspan_titles and whole this list cant be setted in one particular row

Comment: I didn't get it. Looking at your sample data, this solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "fill in" the `NULL` values with the previous value, I would suggest:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             max(colspan_title) over (partition by grp order by id_conf) as new_colspan_title
      from (select t.*,
                   count(colspan_title) over (order by id_conf) as grp
            from t
           ) t
     )
update toupdate
    set colspan_title = new_colspan_title
    where colspan_title is null;
```

Note that this version only uses `colspan_title`.  It does not depend on `NULL` values also have `colspan_no = 0`.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I ve got an answer: Update or insert of view or function 'toupdate' failed because it contains a derived or constant field.

Comment: @DSQuest . . . That's funny.  I just had the `set` columns in the wrong order.

Comment: 0 rows affected

Comment: @DSQuest . . . Are the missing values `NULL`?  Your question suggests that they are.